# underline <a> tag when hovering

Tags: html, css, tags

I want my `<a>` tag gets underlined when hovered. I have the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

     a.hover:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
     </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <a class="hover" style=" text-decoration:none; color:red" href="">Site Map</a>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This:

```
a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
<a  style=" text-decoration:none; color:red" href="">Site Map</a>
```

doesn't work either.

What should I do? What is the problem?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `style` attribute is more [specific](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) than any selector, so it will always be applied last in the cascade (horrible `!important` rules not withstanding). Move the CSS to the stylesheet.

```
a.hover {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.hover:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

(I also suggest a more semantic name for the class).

Answer (score 4):

The inline style overrides the style on the page.

Remove the inline style and uses this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a {text-decoration: none;}
    a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
</style>
```

Also advise you not to use `<style>`, uses an external css file. Will greatly facilitate maintenance.

Comment: Default behaviour is to underline all links all the time.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should write code like:
**([Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/BH7YH/](http://jsfiddle.net/BH7YH/))**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
           a {text-decoration: none; color:red}
           a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
     </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <a class="hover" href="">Site Map</a>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use hover you cannot use inline styles.
you have to write it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">

a.hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:red
}

 a.hover:hover
 {
    text-decoration: underline;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<a class="hover"  href="">Site Map</a>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>ABC</title>
    <style type="text/css">
       a.hover {text-decoration: none; color: red;}
       a.hover:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
             <a class="hover" href="">Site Map</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Read more about css specification.

Answer (score 0):

This might help!

```
a.hover:link {text-decoration: none;}
a.hover:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
```

Comment: No, it won't. `underline-on-hover` is not a valid value for the `text-decoration` property.